# Edit mode using html helper in MVC.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I would like to bind my object to my view using `@Html.DisplayFor` helpers.  Then click an edit button and change them to `@Html.DisplayTextBoxFor` helpers.  I want to make this change client side.

**For Example: Using a View like below**

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("profile", "user", FormMethod.Post)
  @<h2>User Profile</h2>
  @<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(function(m) m.email)
    @Html.DisplayFor(function(m) m.email)
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Edit Mode" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Save" />  
End Using
```

On clicking the "Edit Mode" button, I want the email to become an editable textbox.  Which I will then submit back in my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible. You cannot run server code on the client.

Therefore, you have to choose another option:

- Use a TextBox, also for showing the content, disable and enable them when needed;
- Use a AJAX call to load the edit form from the server. Create an Action that returns a `PartialView` to output and load it in place of the display part (you can use jQuery for example to get the actual results from the server);
- Do a full postback to the server and reload the entire page.

Comment: @JeremyWest: any luck? Need more help?

Comment: I'm afraid I did not ask my question very well. That said this seems to be the right answer to what I asked.  I ended up using a DisplayFor and a TextBoxFor, then toggleling a class on my form (edit-on/edit-off) and showing/hiding with Display or Textbox with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use is DisplayFor() in this case

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.email, new {@readonly = "true", id = "email"})

<input type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Edit Mode" id="edit" />
```

Then with JQuery

```
<script>
    $('#edit').on('click', function () {
       $('#email').attr('readonly', 'false');
    });

</script>
```

You will need to add an id to the button to access.